# How do I pass a function from one Angular 13 router state to another?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Passing data between Angular 13 router states works like a charm like this:

```
this.router.navigate(["/news"], { state: { somevalue: 1 } })
```

Which can then be read like this in the constructor of a component:

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.somevalue
```

But is it generally possible to pass a function?
When trying like this:

```
this.router.navigate([url], { state: { somevalue: () => { console.log("test") } } })
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: Function object could not be cloned.
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation it seems that it's not possible this way.
The data must be some kind of serializable.
This also means that references etc. get lost during the process.

The correct way to do that seems to be a service and a resolver on the route.